# Unable to get bool value in Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to develop login checker. The following code should redirect to HomeScreen when user is loggedin and to LoginPage in User is not loggedin.  But it only gets redirect to LoginScreen() not to HomeScreen() even though it's already logged in.

User Model:

```
class User {
User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.cart,
});

String id;
String name;
String email;
List cart;
```

}

UserController:

```
class UserController extends GetxController {
  RxString id = ''.obs;
  RxBool isLoggedIn = false.obs;
  RxString name = ''.obs;
  RxString email = ''.obs;
  RxString image = ''.obs;
  RxList cart = [].obs;
  final NetworkHandler _handler = NetworkHandler();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getUserDetails();
  }

  getUserDetails() {
    User _user = _handler.userDetails();
    id.value = _user.id;
    if (id.value != '') {
      isLoggedIn.value = true;
    }
    name.value = _user.name;
  }
}
```

Checker Screen

```
class StateCheck extends StatelessWidget {
  var controller = Get.put(UserController());

  StateCheck({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Obx(
      () => controller.isLoggedIn.value
          ? const HomeScreen()
          : const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set login value in [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

> when login success

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("isLogin", true);
```

> log out

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("isLogin", false);
```

> You can Check login state || check this in splash screen for best practice (inside init method)

```
if(prefs.getBool('isLogin')==null||prefs.getBool('isLogin')==false){
 // login screen
}else{
  // home screen
}
```